"Convert Word To PDF in Aspose" - Currency values are getting overlap for AED (United Arab Emirates Dirham) after Aspose Word to PDF conversion
We are using Aspose Linq Engine for generating documents. It is working fine for different-different currency values but when we have value in AED then it works as expected in generated word document but when we convert word document to pdf document then values are getting overlap.
DOCX Document
after converting to PDF Document
Below is sample code to convert to Pdf from Word file and document in word and pdf format.
we are using Aspose.Words" Version="23.8.0" also tried with latest version.
var wordDoc = new Aspose.Words.Document(@"C:\AsposeTemplate\GeneratedDocxFile.docx");
wordDoc.LayoutOptions.TextShaperFactory = HarfBuzzTextShaperFactory.Instance;
wordDoc.Save($"C:/AsposeTemplate/GeneratedPDFFile.pdf");

Here we have added below line because we were facing issue with “Russian Date Format” and after this it gets resolved but we are getting another issue with AED currency values.
wordDoc.LayoutOptions.TextShaperFactory = HarfBuzzTextShaperFactory.Instance;

it should convert same as like DOCX document

The question is answered in Aspose.Words support forum: https://forum.aspose.com/t/currency-values-are-getting-overlap-for-aed-united-arab-emirates-dirham/292325
